# Is possible to identify a PropertyInfo by Property Accessor

Tags: c#, reflection

Supposed I have a object with type is `MethodInfo` like  image.

[image]

How can I know it's `Property Accessor`?

And is there any way to determine `PropertyInfo` of object by the `MethodInfo`?

Comment: I mean Property Accessor is also have type is `MethodInfo`, right? 
Now, I have `MethodInfo`, I wanna get `PropertyInfo` by it

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. So you have the MethodInfo for the property accessor?

Comment: Exactly, and I want to get `PropertyInfo` by it

Comment: I imagine you'll have to first build a lookup from the properties. What are you trying to achieve exactly? Why do you need this information?

Comment: I am using `RealProxy`, and in `Invoke` method, I only get `MethodInfo`. 
But, I wanna know what `Property` called. Do you get what I say?

Comment: `var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty; var prop = [Type].GetType().GetProperties(flags).FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetAccessors(false).Any(a => a.Name.Equals("[Accessor Name]")));`

Comment: Uh, do you know the type of the declaring class for that MethodInfo? I suppose you can get that from MethodInfo's `DeclaringType` property.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way of achieving this is to go from Properties -> Methods to create a lookup of Method -> Property.

I've put this together for retrieving associated accessors from the properties of a given class. First I've created a simple data structure to store the information:

```
public class AccessorDescriptor
{
    public bool IsGetter { get; }
    public bool IsSetter { get; }
    public MethodInfo MethodInfo { get; }
    public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; }

    public AccessorDescriptor(MethodInfo methodInfo, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, bool isGetter, bool isSetter)
    {
        this.MethodInfo = methodInfo;
        this.PropertyInfo = propertyInfo;
        this.IsGetter = isGetter;
        this.IsSetter = isSetter;
    }
}
```

Then a method to extract it:

```
private static IList<AccessorDescriptor> GetPropertyAccessors<TTarget>()
{
    return GetPropertyAccessors(typeof(TTarget));
}

private static IList<AccessorDescriptor> GetPropertyAccessors(Type targetType)
{
    // I believe this should ensure that we catch all defined properties
    var allProps = targetType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.SetProperty);

    // Create a list which will support all of the properties getters and setters
    var result = new List<AccessorDescriptor>(allProps.Count() * 2);

    foreach (var prop in allProps)
    {
        // Get the properties accessors
        foreach (var accessor in prop.GetAccessors(true))
        {
            // Determine if it's a getter or a setter
            if (accessor.ReturnType == typeof(void))
            {
                result.Add(new AccessorDescriptor(accessor, prop, isGetter: false, isSetter: true));
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(new AccessorDescriptor(accessor, prop, isGetter: true, isSetter: false));
            }
        }
    }
    // Return the list
    return result;
}
```

If you need to do a lot of lookups or have a large class, I'd suggest using a dictionary of MethodInfo -> AccessorDescriptor, but it's up to you. You can then use the list (or dictionary) to lookup the PropertyInfo from the MethodInfo of any accessor.

Comment: It's look like I need to prepare a `List` before run anything. I don't want to do that.
And It's so complicate!

Comment: You can refactor this however you need to. Unfortunately I don't think there's any mapping in the direction you want built-in to .NET.